# Webservice and Monodroid

Tags: android, web-services, xamarin.android

I am consuming a [webservice](http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl)  following the guide from this [tutorial](http://monodroyd.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/using-web-services-to-build-your-own-weather-application-in-mono-for-android/) using Mono For Android using c#. Which is running perfectly fine.
Now i have created my own webservice and created a simple test method `GetMyName(String Name)` which is written in vb.net.
If i run this webservice from a remote machine VIA webbrowser it works fine. But its breaking on this line of code when run using Android Emulator. (This code is part of the automatically generated code Refference.cs)

```
public string GetMyName(string Name) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("GetMayName", new object[] {
                        Name});
            return ((string)(results[0]));
        }
```

I am calling my webservice like this

```
 webserviceformobile.Service1 webservice = new webserviceformobile.Service1();
 String myName = webservice.GetMyName("RIZWAN");
```

when i run webservice from browser it outputs the following line:

```
<string xmlns="http://webserviceformobile.com/">rizwan</string>
```

What i am doing wrong ? Is my webservice is returning data in wrong format ?
In example which is working fine i am calling webservice like this

```
com.cdyne.wsf.Weather we = new com.cdyne.wsf.Weather();
com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherReturn wr = new com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherReturn();
wr = we.GetCityWeatherByZIP("02138");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it's breaking"? Is the app crashing? If so, please provide the output from the debug log with the stacktrace http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Comment: The program 'Mono' has exited with code 255

Comment: Again, if the app is crashing, please provide the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your webservice is reachable from the emulator ? This is the exact problem that I was facing.

Comment: well i solve this problem by transferring webservice from local machine to my host.